# Test JASidePanels with Kiwi

Tags: ios, testing, bdd, kiwi

I am trying [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels#uiviewcontrollerjasidepanel-category) with Kiwi, and got following error:

> failed: 'Root side panel controller, wants to show left panel, shows left panel' [FAILED], expected subject to equal 2, got 1

I think I must made some obvious mistake but could not figure out where. Could any one give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

```
#import "Kiwi.h"
#import "JASidePanelController.h"
#import "UIViewController+JASidePanel.h"

SPEC_BEGIN(MSISidePanelControllerSpec)

describe(@"Root side panel controller", ^{

    __block JASidePanelController *sidePanelController;

    beforeEach(^{
        sidePanelController = [[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
    });

    context(@"wants to show left panel", ^{

        beforeEach(^{
            [sidePanelController showLeftPanelAnimated:YES];
        });

        it(@"shows left panel", ^{
            [[theValue(sidePanelController.state) should] equal:theValue(JASidePanelLeftVisible)];
        });
    });
});

SPEC_END
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your setup code (initializing `sidePanelController` and sending `showLeftPanelAnimated:`) are not inside blocks as part of `beforeEach` or similar functions. See [this answer to a similar Kiwi question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16005290/795339) for details.

Comment: Thanks @esker, could you have a look at the updated code? Getting the same error.

Comment: Updated code looks good, that's the correct way to use Kiwi now. The problem might have to do with showing the left panel with animated = YES. Perhaps when animated = YES, `sitePanelController.state` is not immediately set to `JASidePanelLeftVisible`, but only does so asynchronously after animation completes? You could try two things: try `showLeftPanelAnimated:NO` but leave the expectation in the `it` block the same. Or, leave animated = YES and change the expectation to `[[expectFutureValue(theValue(sidePanelController.state)) shouldEventually] equal:...]`.